# How best to store and convert dates and times in .net core booking system?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing a room booking system in .net Core 2.0

I have StartTime and EndTime stored as DateTime variables, but the built-in HTML datetime field is clunky and rather user-unfriendly, so I want the values to display on the page as a date field and a time field.

But I'm wondering what the best way of implementing this is. Should I:

- create some readonly variables within the model (can I do this without creating database fields?)
- create the separate form fields (with jQuery datepicker) and then use JavaScript to write the values of the inputs to hidden fields which store the full DateTime?

(NB I haven't chosen to change the database fields because it is conceivable that a booking might run past midnight. The JavaScript would assume that an early hours endtime is the next day. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, use `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` for your database-backed date/time properties. Whether you end up storing the values in UTC or local time, as long as you have the timezone, you can get to whatever other locale you need. Trust me, this will be invaluable in the long run.

As far as editing goes, make your inputs `datetime-local` types. This isn't actually supported by any browser, but it at least carries more semantic value and who knows, maybe one day browsers will finally get off their collective hind-quarters and do something with it. Breaking it out into separate date and time fields is tempting, so that you can take advantage of built-in browser controls, but it's clunky and prone to error. Use a JavaScript library that provides a good date *and* time control to progressively enhance the input instead. My favorite at the moment is [air-datepicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/). It's lightweight, supports all sorts of scenarios and configuration options, and it's localized.